# Populate field in MySQL with cumulative data from another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'Orders' and a field called 'count'. The Order details are in another table called 'order_details'. How can I populate the field 'count' with the amount of orders from the 'order_details' table.

I am using a foreign key currently between these two tables for joins. The idea behind what I am asking is to keep a dynamic count in the schema of how many orders has been places by a particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a `VIEW` if you want to keep it in the schema.

Comment: Thanks I made a view, and scheduled an import.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the exactly sintax for this in MySql, but the idea is to you create a SP that will make a SUM() of Order_details_Id and insert in Order table field Count.

Finally create a job in MySql to call the SP or create a schedule in windows to call the SP anytime you want (if you are using windows).